# Nginx reverse proxy only specific sub directory and pass through everything else

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, hosts

I have development situation where i have a domain with multiple services:

`https://somewebpage.com`

On this service there are multiple project as subdirectories

- `https://somewebpage.com` <- landing page
- `https://somewebpage.com/api` <- rest api server
- `https://somewebpage.com/app` <- my app

So is it possible (and how) to setup nginx and hosts file to reverse proxy only `https://somewebpage.com/app` to my local build `http://localhost:3000`?

The issue is that when app is deployed is has no issues accessing `/api` rest server but when serving locally my nginx reverse proxy intercepts `landing page` and `rest api server` urls as well.

My nginx configuration looks like:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    
    index index.html;

    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_buffering off;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name somewebpage.com;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name somewebpage.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/ccertificate.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        location /app {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my `/etc/hosts` i have:

```
127.0.0.1    somewebpage.com
```

Are there any other tricks on how to achieve similar result?

The reason why i try to do this is that if i do it from my `localhost:3000` it will respond with `CORS` errors and reject my calls to `/api`.

Or is this too much of security hazard and i have to ask for other way of access to `/api`?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with one solution which works for me.

`somewebpage.com` points to `xx.xx.xx.xx` static IP address so i just added another proxy forward to that IP address instead of URL similar to Tero Kilkanen answer.

```
  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass https://xx.xx.xx.xx;
  }
```

That way `/etc/hosts` file will not intercept my `somewebpage.com` request as request will bypass domain resolve.

So in the end i ended up with following nginx configuration which worked for me:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    
    index index.html;

    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_buffering off;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name somewebpage.com;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name somewebpage.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/ccertificate.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        location /app {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass https://xx.xx.xx.xx;
        }
    }
}
```

This solution might not work for everyone due to multiple IP addresses behind the sceenes or dynamic IP addresses or something else. But it worked for me and it was good enough for development purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

This tells nginx how to handle requests that don't match the other specified `location`. For more information how nginx selects `location` block to use, read [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).